# sendmail takes forever

Tags: postfix

I'm using postfix on ubuntu 12.04 server, with help from https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Postfix

after setting up sasl as above guide, I tried sendmail - and sendmail just hangs.

here's what I've done:

```
# cat mail.mail
To: <myid>@gmail.com
Subject: test mail
From: root@<myserver.com>

a test mail

# sendmail -vt mail.mail
(a blank line displayed forever and i have to Ctrl+C out of it)
```

though I can send mail via telnet.

```
#telnet localhost 25
EHLO <myserver.com>
MAIL FROM: root@<myserver.com>
RCPT TO: <myid>@gmail.com
DATA
test mail
.

(mail sent to <myid>@gmail.com, thrown directly to junks though)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sendmail` doesn't accept a message file as a parameter, it reads the message from stdin. You need to pipe the message text into `sendmail`:

```
sendmail -vt < mail.mail
```